Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'RNCSafeAreaContext': java.lang.NullPointerException with React Native 0.74.3
This is showing up in Crashlytics with React Native 0.74.3.  Anyone have a clue why this is happening?
          Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'RNCSafeAreaContext': java.lang.NullPointerException, js engine: hermes, stack:
requireModule@1:115914
get@1:116072
anonymous@1:873094
loadModuleImplementation@1:90322
guardedLoadModule@1:89864
metroRequire@1:89486
anonymous@1:872896
loadModuleImplementation@1:90322
guardedLoadModule@1:89864
metroRequire@1:89486
anonymous@1:868773
loadModuleImplementation@1:90322
guardedLoadModule@1:89821
metroRequire@1:89486
LaunchScreen@1:708502
renderWithHooks@1:398864
beginWork@1:447652
performUnitOfWork@1:433665
workLoopSync@1:432732
renderRootSync@1:432563
flushSyncWorkAcrossRoots_impl@1:388322
scheduleUpdateOnFiber@1:430027
enqueueSetState@1:445101
anonymous@1:309940
anonymous@1:4061791
dispatch@1:937063
rehydrate@1:1301051
_rehydrate@1:1295500
anonymous@1:1295698
anonymous@1:240994
_callTimer@1:239942
_callReactNativeMicrotasksPass@1:240087
callReactNativeMicrotasks@1:242087
__callReactNativeMicrotasks@1:103104
anonymous@1:102186
__guard@1:102942
flushedQueue@1:102097
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@1:101953

       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:65)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:146)
       at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:233)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

